# Face encodings using dlib in android

Tags: android, encoding, face-detection, dlib

I am trying to use dlib in android. I integrated dlib in android app and able to get the face landmarks but I need to get the encodings(128 points) signature of the face also. below is my code to get landmarks, can someone help me on how to get encodings? Thanks.

```
 for (VisionDetRet ret : results) {

            // Get landmark
            ArrayList<Point> landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();
            for (Point point : landmarks) {
                int pointX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
                int pointY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);
                canvas.drawCircle(pointX, pointY, 2, paint);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The encoding signature is not include in the VisionDetRet objects.

My guess is you using the dlib android by tzutalin 
https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android

If that's the case you will need to write your own cpp code or modify the code that already there to get that information and then compile the native codes yourself in Java to get it working. Here is a pretty good directory for face recognition on android, however it still does not return the face encoder but you can refer to it to modify the cpp and return the information that you want
 https://github.com/gv22ga/dlib-face-recognition-android 
 The cpp code is in jni/jni_recognition folder. 
Hope this help